# Getting comboBox value for parameters

Tags: c#

For my project I'm using a library and it has a list of pre-defined options. I want to be able to choose from a comboBox so I don't need to edit the source everytime.

main code: Searches for a player. Level can either be set as Gold, Silver, Bronze or All. I want to be able to choose that from comboBox. The error at the end shows when I click a button to run this code.

```
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
{
    Page = 1,
    Level = comboBox1.SelectedItem == null ? Level.All : (Level)(comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value,
    //usually set like this Level - Level.Gold,
};
```

comboBox code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Level level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Level)))
    {
        ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
        item.Text = level.ToString();
        item.Value = level;
        comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

ComboboxItem code:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

I thought that all of this would work but it give an error saying NullReferenchExeption was unhanded by user code. and Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I really need help with getting this to work.

All help is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: Where have u defined comboBox1

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? Also you need to make sure a item in the combobox is selected

Comment: comboBox1 is on the windows forms application. The second code snippet is inside of the thread.

Comment: The error comes up when I search for the player, when I click a button to read the first peice of code

Comment: This [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2802352a-6aed-4351-913f-6391d361eecb/comboxselectedvalue-is-null-after-item-is-selected) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind the `comboBox1` directly from enum as below

```
comboBox1.DataSource  =Enum.GetNames(typeof(Level));
```

then if you need to get selected enum

```
Level level ; 
if( Enum.TryParse<Level>(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), out level))
{ 
        var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
        {
            Page = 1,
            Level =level 
        };
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I get an error saying Cannot pass 'level' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'foreach iteration variable' Sorry if I'm being stupid, I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: you don't need to add items in `SelectedIndexChanged` if you using my answer. remove or comment item adding code in `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: I think that I've almost got it working. Two errors aren't going away though. Here's a screenshot of my code and the errors. http://ttgstarify.info/i/ffc67da.png                                    I think it's because it needs to end with a ',' but I'm not sure how I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

After running what you have posted here - the only time that I receive a `NullReferenchExeption` is when I click the search button when nothing has been selected in the `Combobox` yet.

You need to check for null first. Like so...

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
     var searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
     var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
     {
          Page = 1,
          Level = (Level)(comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value,
          //usually set like this Level - Level.Gold,
     };
}
```

Comment: I checked for null and it worked! New error though :(. When I click the search button it now says "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set." and it then highlights comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

Comment: Remove the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the combobox. I don't believe there is any need for it as far as I can tell. You're binding the Level enum as the DataSource of the combobox now.

Comment: I get a lot of errors when I do it, though. Do you mean just remove it from here?   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: If you are using VS - just go into the properties of you Combobox - then go to events (orange lightning bolt) and remove it from there. Otherwise it's going to be set in the `Designer` code as well and it's easier and safer to do that way then manually removing it.